# Javascript onclick function not working laravel blade

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, sweetalert2

Developing delete function that needs confirmation before deleting with sweetalert2. 
Here is my code tried

```
<button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect" type="button" onclick="book({{ $book->id }})">delete</button>
<form id="delete-form-{{ $book->id }}" action="{{ url('/library/books/', ['id' => $book->id]) }}" method="POST">
    {!! method_field('delete') !!}
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
</form>
```

And here is my javascript that I am pushing in my master blade

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function book(id) {
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
        buttonsStyling: false,
        reverseButtons: true
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('delete-form-'+id).submit();
        } else if (
            // Read more about handling dismissals
            result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel
        ) {
            swal(
                'Cancelled',
                'Your data is safe :)',
                'error'
            )
        }
    })
}
```

Use stack in master blade

```
@stack('customjs')
```

When clicking the delete button gets an error. Error is

```
books:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: book is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (books:4)
```

How can I solve this and show sweet alert before delete item?

Comment: Do you see the js function in the page source?

Comment: Yes, Its show in page source

Comment: I think you should provide more codes or put the whole page source in here

Comment: Which part of code i should share ?

Comment: I think the whole source code (from browser) is good enough

Comment: That problem was in my swal function code and i have solved it. Thanks, everyone for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

in your master blade at the bottom or header

```php
@stack('customjs')
```

In you blade

```php
@push('customjs')
<script type="text/javascript">
    function book()
    {
        //enter code here
    }
</script>
@endpush
```

Your button

```html
<button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect" type="button" onclick="book({{ $book->id }})">delete</button>
```

---

If you use laravel u propably use jquery wich makes it way easier.

your button

```html
<button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect clickHandleButton" type="button">delete</button>
<form action="{{ url('/library/books/', ['id' => $book->id]) }}" method="POST">
    {!! method_field('delete') !!}
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
</form>
```

Your javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickHandleButton', (e) => { //replaces function book()
   $(e.currentTarget).next('form').submit();
   //find the form next to the clicked button and submit the form.
});
```